# Any good tutorials / resources to learn Win32 GDI?

Tags: windows, winapi, gdi

So far i have been searching on google and haven't fount a single good tutorial which is comprehensive. Does any one know of any good site or book which teaches Win32 GDI?

Comment: Nope. Wish you the best of the best of luck... GDI is a pain in the rear.

Comment: GDI/GDI+ are deprecated IIRC, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectWrite is the replacement

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: Windows GDI (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145203%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Yes. But i want tutorials or books , not documentation.

Comment: i think you can reffer the book : Windows 2000 Graphics API Black Book by Damon Chandler and Michael Fötsch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Petzold (Programming Windows, now in its >=5th edition) has good coverage.

GDI has been replaced by Direct2D and DirectWrite, which are available down to Vista, and substantially more performant and flexible. You might want to double-check that you really need to support XP, which is already past end-of-life.

Martyn

Comment: Thanks. But that book was written like more than a decade ago. Haven't the Apis changed since then?

Comment: DirectWrite has [issues with text rendering quality](http://www.basschouten.com/blog1.php/font-rendering-gdi-versus-directwrite), though.

Comment: That book was written over a decade ago, but there hasn't been a lot of change in GDI since then. Remember that the OS you are trying to target was itself released a decade ago (2001). Certainly from a tutorial perspective, there isn't much extra to say about GDI post Win2k.

Comment: That's disheartening. Looks like M$ doesn't care about GDI or the WinApi anymore. Especially since WPF came. :(

Comment: GDI (1985) has been deprecated for a while. GDI+ replaced it as the recommended technology in Windows XP (2001), and DirectWrite/Direct2D in 2009. And as you say WPF was added as a hihger-level retained-mode option in 2006, supported all the way down to XP. And in today's Windows 7, all four of these technologies are supported and have their apps still running.

Comment: @Martin GDI has been neither replaced or deprecated. But Petzold is still the best way to learn GDI.

Comment: @burning I wouldn't worry about the long term future of Win32. It was written off 10 years ago when .net was released and it's still going strong.

Comment: Mark's DX blog entry should be useful to clarify the recommendations between GDI and D2D:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/directx/archive/2009/09/29/comparing-direct2d-and-gdi.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I found [bobobobo's blog](http://bobobobo.wordpress.com/) to be quite helpful for getting started with Win32 and related concepts.

Comment: booboobooboobooboo... jk +1, that's an awesome site, I find it pretty helpful myself too. :)